# Is it possible to compute per-example gradients efficiently in TensorFlow, in just one graph run?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient

TD;DR: is there a way to evaluate f'(x1), f'(x2), ..., f'(xn) in just one graph run, in a vectorized form? Where f'(x) is the derivative of f(x).

Something like:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[100])
f = tf.square(x)
f_grad = tf.multiple_gradients(x) # f_grad contains f'(x[0]), f'(x[1]), ...
```

More specifically, I'm trying to implement Black Box Stochastic Variational Inference (BBSVI) manually (I know I could use a library like [Edward](http://edwardlib.org/), but I'm trying to implement it myself).
At one point, I need to compute the mean of f'(x)g(x) across many different values of x (x1, x2, ..., xn), where f(x) and g(x) are two functions, and f'(x) is the derivative of f(x).

Using TensorFlow's autodiff feature, I can compute f'(x1), f'(x2), ..., f'(xn), by simply calling `f_prime.eval(feed_dict={x: xi})` once for each value xi in (x1, x2, ..., xn).  This is not efficient at all: I would like to use a vectorized form instead, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Perhaps using `tf.stop_gradient()` somehow? Or using the `grad_ys` argument in `tf.gradients()`?

Answer (score 3):

After a bit of digging, it seems that it is not trivial to compute per-example gradients in TensorFlow, because this library performs standard back-propagation to compute the gradients (as do other deep learning libraries like PyTorch, Theano and so on), which never actually computes the per-example gradients, it directly obtains the sum of the per-example gradients. Check out [this discussion](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4897) for more details.

However, there are some techniques to work around this issue, at least for some use cases. For example, the paper [Efficient per-example gradient computation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.01799) by Ian Goodfellow explains how to efficiently compute per-example vectors containing the sum of squared derivatives.  Here is an excerpt from the paper showing the computation (but I highly encourage you read the paper, it is very short):

[image]

This algorithm is O(mnp) instead of O(mnp²), where m is the number of examples, n is the number of layers in the neural net, and p is the number of neurons per layer.  So it is much faster than the naive approach (i.e., performing back-prop once per example), especially when p is large, and even more when using a GPU (which speeds up vectorized approaches by a large factor).

Answer (score 2):

On Tensorflow, it exactly demonstrates the example for per example gradient as below:

```
# Computing per-example gradients
batch_size = 10
num_features = 32
layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

def model_fn(arg):
  with tf.GradientTape() as g:
    inp, label = arg
    inp = tf.expand_dims(inp, 0)
    label = tf.expand_dims(label, 0)
    prediction = layer(inp)
    loss = tf.nn.l2_loss(label - prediction)
  return g.gradient(loss, (layer.kernel, layer.bias))

inputs = tf.random.uniform([batch_size, num_features])
labels = tf.random.uniform([batch_size, 1])
per_example_gradients = tf.vectorized_map(model_fn, (inputs, labels))
assert per_example_gradients[0].shape == (batch_size, num_features, 1)
assert per_example_gradients[1].shape == (batch_size, 1)
```

You can refer to [the official link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/vectorized_map) for further details using `vectorized_map`.

Comment: Using the above to get a gradient I get: `WARNING:tensorflow:Using a while_loop for converting ResourceGather` is that always throwing that?

Comment: Can this be used with tf.compute_gradients, so that I can compute the gradients per example, then perform ops on them, THEN aggregate them and use the aggregate in tf.apply_gradients?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tf.vectorized_map(forward_and_backward_fn, batch_of_inputs)` to compute per example gradients efficiently.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. Read how to [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).